# How to rename git branch name using Eclipse

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I created a remote branch called `origin/feature-BRANCH-NAME` from `origin/master` and i accidentally typed a wrong branch name and I want to rename it using Eclipse.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ***From within eclipse:***

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Renaming_an_Existing_Branch

***Renaming an Existing Branch***

- From the Team menu on a Project node
- Select Team `>` Advanced `>` Rename Branch...
- On the branch selection dialog, select the branch to rename
- Enter the new branch name and click **OK**

---

### ***`Using git command line:`***

```
# rename a local branch
git branch -m origin/feature-BRANCH-NAM <newname>
```

### ***`How to rename a remote branch?`***

Delete the old branch and push a new one with the new name

```
 # delete the remote branch
 git push origin - -delete <old name>

 # checkout the new branch (after renamed as explained above)
 git checkout <local new branch>

 # push the new branch name
 git push origin <new name>
```

Comment: The first method - from Eclipse IDE, don't change the remote branch, only the local connected